# Eureka-Server Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I created few microservices and eureka-server and register all my microservices to the eureka-server and everything is working fine in local. following configurations i am providing in my services

1. Eureka Server

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false           
    fetch-registry: false                 
                                          
server:
  port: 8761
```

2. Microservices

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:                                    
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

So my doubt is in local everything is fine but when i'll deploy this in any cloud server then will this 'eureka.instance.hostname' property work over their? my microservices will be able to register with the eureka-server with the same url 'http://localhost:8761/eureka'?

I am not aware about this whether it'll work or not when i'll deploy my service in any server. Right now i am just learning microservices in spring boot.

Comment: Although in the answers it says that you need to have a gateway that is not true if you aren't going to get any external access to your services. You can simply implement a ribbon client which will fetch the service addresses from your eureka instance with the proper config. You should do it for each services which needs to make a call to other services

Comment: I already implemented the API Gateway (on port: 9093) and i am able to call microservices using url "localhost:9093/user/userWithRatingsUsingFeign/1" but my quesion is when i'll deploy my microservices in any cloud environment then will my microservices able to register on eureka-server that i want because right now we are providing an hard coded url -- localhost:8761/eureka to register my microservice and eureka.instance.hostname = localhost? will these properties holds true whn i'll deploy my application? 
my github link  -- https://github.com/ayushdgupta/SpringBoot3-APIGateway-Microservice

Comment: My thinking is when i'll deploy my eureka server on any cloud environment then it's IP Address and port will change and right now i am providing a constant url to my microservices to register on eureka, so how can i provide a dynamic url where there is no need for me to change anything when i'll deploy my application to any server?

Comment: You are right on the configurations. If you don't deploy all this services into a single host then localhost will not work. eureka related config should be overridden for production env.

Comment: Then how we will connect our microservices with Eureka because IP Addresses in cloud environment or at any server will not be fixed, they are variable right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement API gateway. By using API gateway you can access all the services by using Ip address of eureka server and port number of API gateway.

You have to register API gateway on eureka server.

This will be your application.yml for API gateway.

```
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY

  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: USER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/**
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

This will be main class of API gateway.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

You need below mentioned dependencies in API gateway.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I already implemented the API Gateway (with port: 9093) and i am able to call my microservices using url "http://localhost:9093/user/userWithRatingsUsingFeign/1" but my quesion is when i'll deploy my microservices in any cloud environment then will my microservices able to register on eureka-server that i want because right now we are providing an hard coded url -- http://localhost:8761/eureka to register my microservice and eureka.instance.hostname = localhost? will these properties holds true whn i'll deploy my application?

Comment: My thinking is when i'll deploy my eureka server on any cloud environment then it's IP Address and port will change and right now i am providing a constant url to my microservices to register on eureka, so how can i provide a dynamic url where there is no need for me to change anything when i'll deploy my application to any server?

Comment: yes you can provide dynamic URL by using ip of eureka server. You don't need to use localhost. Your url will become like this : http://"ip of eureka server":"port number of api gateway"/user/userWithRatingsUsingFeign/1. And you can also give the name to all the services which are registered with eureka server and after this your url will become like this : http://USER-SERVICE/user/userWithRatingsUsingFeign/1 and you don,t have to pass the port number or hostname everytime